# Spring @Async with CompletableFuture

Tags: spring, completable-future

I have a doubt about this code:

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> doFoo() {
    CompletableFuture<String> fooFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();  

    try {
        String fooResult = longOp();
        fooFuture.complete(fooResult);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fooFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
    }

    return fooFuture;
}
```

The question is: does doFoo return fooFuture only after longOp has finished (either correctly or exceptionally) and is therefore returning already completed futures or is Spring doing some magic and returning before executing the body? If the code is blocking on longOp(), how would you express that the computation is being fed to an executor?

Perhaps this? Any other way?

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<String> doFoo() {

    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            String fooResult = longOp();
            completableFuture.complete(fooResult);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            completableFuture.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
    });
    return completableFuture;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `@EnableAsync` to your application

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Spring actually does all of the work behind the covers so you don't have to create the `CompletableFuture` yourself.
Basically, adding the `@Async` annotation is **as if** you called your original method (without the annotation) like:

```
CompletableFuture<User> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doFoo());
```

As for your second question, in order to feed it to an executor, you can specify the exectutor bean name in the [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) of the `@Async` annotation, like so:

```
    @Async("myExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<User> findUser(String usernameString) throws InterruptedException {
        User fooResult = longOp(usernameString);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(fooResult);
    }
```

The above would basically be the following **as if** you called your original method, like:

```
CompletableFuture<User> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doFoo(), myExecutor);
```

And all of your `exceptionally` logic you would do with the returned `CompletableFuture` from that method.

Comment: I see, so basically the @Async annotation is lifting my method into the CompletableFuture, exceptions automatically captured and tucked into the a completedExceptionally... ugh, I've done too much Scala lately not to get confused :D

Comment: Yep, so `get()` will return your `String` result and/or propogate the exception up, or you can complete it `exceptionally` with a supplier

Comment: does it run even if i never .join() or .get()?

Comment: Does the method return type always have to be CompletableFuture or can we have Future as well? What are the advantages of the former

Comment: @JaisonVarghese The return type for an `@Async` annotated method must be void, or a Future (so, a CompletableFuture works too). The CompletableFuture is a more recent API that provide more functionality than the Future (Java 8 vs Java 5, respectively).

Comment: One question....is CompletableFuture must for @Async annotation? Does it not work with Custom Java data types ?

Comment: Like @FrenchFigaro said, only void or Future is possible.  Future is an interface and CompletableFuture one of the implementations.  Custom Java data types can be wrapped in CompletableFuture i.e. CompletableFuture<CustomType>.  CompletableFuture provides methods like join instead of using the method get where you have to put that in try..catch block.