# Spring batch - Keep the server running

Tags: java, spring-batch, vaadin

I made this spring batch project (csv to database, classic) - works fine: https://github.com/Tyvain/Spring-Batch-Generic-Bulk

On a separate project, I made an app with vaadin where I can upload a file works fine:
https://github.com/Tyvain/vaadin-simple-upload-file

-> We need to trigger the job when a file is uploaded.

So I regrouped the 2 projects into one app, with these steps:

1. disable batch: job.enabled: false (in application.yml)
2. add required vaadin librairies to the pom
3. add the view (MainView.java).

Sources of this modifications: https://github.com/Tyvain/Spring-Batch-Generic-Bulk/tree/include-vaadin-upload-page

At this point, I am still not sure how to launch the job, but I face another problem: when I launch the app, it stops. The server, that stay up in the vaadin app, does not stay up here.

Edit:
when I remove those annotation from my job configuration, the server stays up:

```
//@Configuration
//@EnableBatchProcessing
```

1/ Is it possible to keep my server running with spring-batch enable?

2/ is this a wrong practice ?

Solution working: https://github.com/Tyvain/ProcessUploadedFile-Vaadin_SpringBatch

Comment: A standalone Spring Batch job would normally run, then stop.  The vaadin server side support starts, then keeps running until you shut it down. So - it might be better to merge your Spring Batch project into your Vaadin project (which will already stay up)  - then run an instance of your Spring Batch job within your Vaadin server, after each file upload occurs...

Comment: Ok, but I don't think it would work. I would like to understand what is the difference between the 2 projects that make spring-batch project stop. I compared both configuration, and I dont understand. They are pretty much the same.

Comment: I am guessing a Vaadin project runs within a web server, so the browser can connect to it and download the vaading application.  That web server might be started transparently - but it will be there, and will stay up.  A Spring Batch app, on the other hand, will "just" run its job when it's started, then stop - since the job is done.

Comment: yes. I find that when I remove spring-batch annotations, the server stays up. But then I might loose the advantages of spring batch I think (entries in job executions tables etc..)

Comment: It think it behaves as a 'spring-batch' project, as soon as a bean in the spring context has an import from from org.springframework.batch.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a Spring Batch job from within a web server, you need to setup a `JobLauncher` that runs your job asynchronously in the background. This is explained in details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer

You would need to use an asynchronous `TaskExecutor` implementation (such as `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`). See example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher

Answer (score -1):

If you want to process uploaded file right after it has been uploaded, the spring-batch is not the right approach. I would recommend to process it in background thread after upload using @Async and CompletableFuture, see more info here: [Spring @Async with CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351435/spring-async-with-completablefuture)

Comment: but then I loose all the feature that spring-batch brings (steps, job execution table etc..).