# How does the jvm return a Future object reference before the asynchronous method has completed

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, jvm, java.util.concurrent

Consider the following code

```java
class Test {
  public void method1() {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = helloFuture();
    assertEquals("done", future.get());
  }
}

class Service {
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<String> helloFuture() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("hello future");
    Thread.sleep(100);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("done");
  }
}
```

The `helloFuture` method only returns the CompletableFuture in the last line **after** it has done its work. But we get a reference to the returned CompletableFuture in the test method **when** the `helloFuture` starts executing and start to wait for it in the main thread (using the `get` method). So how does the calling method get a reference to the `CompletableFuture` even before it is created in the `helloFuture` method?

This is in the context of Spring, but even for regular `ExecutorService.submit` I have the same question. I guess it is possible that in a regular `ExecutorService` the internal implementation first creates and returns a `Future` object in the calling thread and queues up the task to be executed in the thread pool.

Comment: Letting handling of `InterruptedException` aside, it’s equivalent to `CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new Service()) .thenComposeAsync(Service::helloFuture);`

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've shown, you only create the `Future` after `helloFuture` has finished executing. There is no magic going on there: The method runs in exactly the order you think it does by reading the code. The method uses `CompletableFuture.completedFuture`, which does exactly what you think: It returns a new `Future` instance in an already-completed state. And the `helloFuture` call in the `Test` class will block until all of that is done.

Comment: ... and now I noticed the `Async` annotation which probably means Spring is providing magic. F'ing Spring, always making intuitive, easy to read code harder to understand...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47351924/596720 - looks like it.